# Why is my capsule getting flinged in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I am trying to make a rigidbody based movement script in Unity so that I can make a weird shooter game but in the way I am making the script my capsule/player just gets flung and I do not know why. Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class move : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool isJumping;
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.y, Input.GetAxis("Vertical")), ForceMode.VelocityChange);
    }

}
```

I tried changing the capsule collider to a box collider but it still resulted in the capsule getting flung. If it helps, the ground I am using is a plane and the components on my capsule are Capsule (Mesh Filter), Mesh Renderer, Move (Script), Rigidbody, and Box Collider. Also do not get angry at me for repeating GetComponent() because when I tried to make it a variable Unity gave me an error so I just decided not to try.

Answer (score 0):

You are applying the direct velocity control mindset, but you're using an acceleration API. Your code **adds** the players current vertical velocity `GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.y` (up or down on Y) every physics tick as soon as you have any movement on that axis. Effectively your speed doubles every 0.02 seconds.

Gravity pulls you down, your falling speed starts doubling, the capsule makes contact with the ground and tumbles in a random direction continuously doubling its fall speed.

What you basically need to do is not touch the y component of Addforce. The rigidbody already preserves your velocity. You can simply replace `GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.y` with 0.

```csharp
GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical")), ForceMode.VelocityChange);
```